# How to replace the deprecated ScriptDb with Mongodb using URL Fetch service?

Tags: mongodb, google-apps-script

Due to the recent ScriptDb [deprecation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/script-db) I need to replace it. I chose MongoDb(as I need noSQL db). Google does not provide any guides on how to connect mongo. It's just said that one should use [mongolab](http://docs.mongolab.com/) and [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/).

I created a data base on mongolab. They gave me the following ways of connecting to it:

```
To connect using the shell:
   mongo ds045679.mongolab.com:45679/prjacc -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
To connect using a driver via the standard URI (what's this?):
   mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds045679.mongolab.com:45679/prjacc
```

[But there's no driver for google script](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/)
so I can't figure out how to replace my old code:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
// work with db...
```

with access to mongo using URL Fetch Service.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Beware you will have severe limits on calls to urlFetch :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I've found a solution.
MongoDB also provides the third way of accessing the DB, though they strongly recommend to use 2 ways described in my question. This is to use their REST API:

[image]

So it seems we should pass this url `https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases?apiKey=<your-api-key>` to the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` function.

Please correct me if I'm not right. Any additions and notes are appreciated.